# Add a NoData buffer to a raster with rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, vrt, tiling

I am currently trying to extract Web Mercator tiles from a Geotiff raster using rasterio VRT (version 1.0rc5). The tiles sometimes exceed the extent of the raster, which causes me trouble.

Reading the tile with `data = vrt.read(window=tile_window, out_shape=tile_shape)` gives me corrupted result, instead of a cleanly cropped tile (I would expect to have NoData values out of the raster extent). According to the doc, the parameter `boundless=True` seems to do what I want, but it does not work for WarpedVRT.

I am trying to find a workaround by adding a NoData buffer around my raster. Is it possible, and, if so, how can I do it?

My simplified code:

```
with rasterio.open(image) as src:

    extent = ...
    tile_shape = ...

    with WarpedVRT(src, crs='EPSG:3857', resampling=Resampling.bilinear) as vrt:

        # Window for reading the dataset
        tile_window = vrt.window(extent.x_min, extent.y_min, extent.x_max, extent.y_max)

        # Read tile content (boundless mode does not work yet for WarpedVRT)
        data = vrt.read(window=tile_window, out_shape=tile_shape)
```

*Edit to illustrate the issue:*

The tile I want to extract (there are 3 or 4 rows of pixels et the very bottom of the tile):

[image]

What I get from rasterio.vrt:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried defining src_nodata and dst_nodata? What values do you get where you expect no data values?

Comment: Hi Liam, I did not set specific nodata values. I have edited my question to show what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my issue, without adding a padding buffer around the raster. The corrupted result was caused by the option `out_shape=tile_shape` when reading the VRT.

Without this option, `vrt.read()` returns an array that contains only the raster data located inside the window; in my illustration, its size was something like (4,500). I had to manually resample this array in order to fit the tile size, then fill the rest of the tile with NoData value.